# how can i do motion geo point on android?

Tags: android, location, android-mapview, point, geo

i wanna display user location on mapview and i could it. but i cant update geopoint  when user move to another location at this time - when look the map- how can i do that?

```
     List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
     Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(resID);
     HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new        HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)latd,(int)lond);
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, name, name);
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `onLocationChanged()` of your `Location Listener` you need to write the same code again,

```
     List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
     mapOverlays.clear() // add this to remove previous
     Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(resID); 
     HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new        HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this); 
     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)latd,(int)lond); 
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, name, name); 
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem); 
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```